# Redirection with React Router

Tags: reactjs

I have created a login page.
What I would like to do now is redirect the user to the dashboard once he is logged in.
it is the first time that I interface with React Router and I don't know how to do it.

login.js

```
const renderForm = (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-container">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="uname" required></input>
                {renderErrorMessage("uname")}
            </div>

            <div className="input-container">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" required></input>
                {renderErrorMessage("pass")}
            </div>
            <div className="button-container">
                <input type="submit"></input>
            </div>
        </form>
    );

    return (
        <div className="login">
            <div className="login-form">
                <div className="title">Login</div>
                {isSubmitted ? <div>you are logged</div> : renderForm}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I would like to redirect the user to dashboard.js

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Import {UseNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate=UseNavigate()
```

Then inside your function

```
{isSubmitted ? navigate('/newpath') :renderForm}
```

Comment: Case matters. This will error for both `Import` and `UseNavigate`. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Comment: In fact I get this error: index.tsx:24 Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.